# python smtplib set timeout

Tags: python, smtplib

i trying write small application for send email every day whit status of my server, i am use smtplib, bat have little problem i don't know can set connection timeout ! im try whit smtp.setdefaulttimeout(30) bat not work

```
def connect(host,user,password)
  try:
    smtp = smtplib.SMTP(host)
        smtp.login(user, password)
        code = smtp.ehlo()[0]
        if not (200 <= code <= 299):
            code = smtp.helo()[0]
 except:
     pass
```

how set connection timeout to this function ? thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From Python 2.6 you can set a timeout in SMTP library ([official documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html)):

```
class smtplib.SMTP([host[, port[, local_hostname[, timeout]]]])
```

*"if not specified, the global default timeout setting will be used"*

If you use an older version of Python (< 2.6 ) you need to set a socket default timeout:

```
import socket
socket.setdefaulttimeout(120)
```

For me worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

While internally `smtplib` uses `socket` then you can use `socket.setdefaulttimeout()` before connecting to host:

```
def connect(host,user,password):
    try:
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(2 * 60)
        smtp = smtplib.SMTP(host)
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.7 has an extra timeout parameter that can be used:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP

This parameter is not present in Python 2