# SMTPLIB timeout not working even with socket timeout set

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtplib

Please how do I set `timeout` for `smtplib` or can someone explain why it doesn't work for me? I have found answer on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21826829/python-smtplib-set-timeout) but trying it myself, i found it doesn't work.

Here is sample code which takes 30 to 40 seconds to through exception even when `timeout` is set to 10 seconds.

```
import time, socket
from smtplib import SMTP
socket.setdefaulttimeout(10)

start_time = time.time()

try:
    print("hello")
    smtp_server = SMTP(host='smtp.office365.com', port=25, timeout=10)
    elapsed = int(time.time() - start_time)
    print('Elapsed Time: {:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}\n'.format(elapsed // 3600, (elapsed % 3600 // 60), elapsed % 60))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    elapsed = int(time.time() - start_time)
    print('Time + Exception: {:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}\n'.format(elapsed // 3600, (elapsed % 3600 // 60), elapsed % 60))
```

Note: The error is due to wrong smtp port, the goal is to fail fast if no connection can be established. If i use port 587  which is the correct port. It all happens in less than a seconds.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the SMTP class is internally calling `socket.create_connection()`, which isn't necessarily opening a single socket connection.

Instead, it's iterating over all the IP addresses returned by `socket.getaddrinfo()` and attempting to open a connection to each IP address.

Each IP address takes 10 seconds to fail, so if it takes 40 seconds to timeout you know that the code tried connecting to 4 IP addresses before failing.